# Does ignite C++ client support publish subscribe

Tags: c++, publish-subscribe, ignite

I am currently reading input from an ignite cache using C++ client.
For performance improvements I am trying to switch to pub sub model. But I was unable to find documentation about pub sub mechanism using C++ api.

Does ignite C++ support publish subscribe mechanism

Answer (score 1):

[Apache Ignite C++ supports Continuous Queries](https://apacheignite-cpp.readme.io/docs/continuous-queries) which let you subscribe to updates on a cache, get called back when data is published to that cache.